# Combine 2 SQL queries into one

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an article table which contains all the articles of my website.

Design looks like this:

```
id | user_id | name | date
```

I also have a followers table which contains all followers that follow each article

It's design looks like this:

```
id | article_id | user_id | date
```

Currently I have a SQL query which brings me 50 articles that exist ordered by date

```
SELECT id,user_id,name,date
FROM articles
ORDER BY date
LIMIT 50
```

I also have one more query which shows me 50 of the followers of an article

```
SELECT id, article_id, user_id, date
FROM followers
WHERE article_id = 5
LIMIT 50
```

How can i make this one query so I don't have to call 2 queries since I find it useless and could take more time to load?

Comment: Do you want the 50 most recent followers of each article?

Comment: @ZaneBien it could be any 50 followers but 50 most recent could do the trick as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM articles
    ORDER BY date
    LIMIT 50
) a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT aa.*
    FROM followers aa
    LEFT JOIN followers bb ON aa.article_id = bb.article_id AND aa.id < bb.id
    GROUP BY aa.id
    HAVING COUNT(1) < 50
) b ON a.id = b.article_id
```

This gets the 50 oldest articles joined with the 50 latest followers for each of those articles.

---

**It is also quite flexible:**

*Change `aa.id < bb.id` to `aa.id > bb.id` to get the 50 first followers.*

*Change `ORDER BY date` to `ORDER BY date DESC` to get the 50 latest articles.*

*Change `LIMIT n` where `n` represents the amount of articles you want to retrieve.*

*Change `HAVING COUNT(1) < n` where `n` represents the amount of followers you want to retrieve per article.*

And you can mix all four up to facilitate any combination you want.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT a.id, a.user_id, a.name, a.date, f.id, f.article_id, f.user_id, f.date 
FROM articles a, followers f 
WHERE f.article_id = 5 
ORDER BY a.date 
LIMIT 50
```

Comment: if an article has 500 followers will it add them into an object with 0,1,2,3,4,5 indexes and inside their data?